# Switch az login from Windows Account Manager back to Web Access manager

Tags: azure-cli, windows-11, azure-authentication, azureclicredential

Does any know what the detailed process is to switch between the Windows Account Manager and WAM for logging into the `az` cli?

Windows 11 has (what I believe to be called) a *Windows Account Manager* in the Settings app. It is possible to add multiple accounts used by other apps. I have seen the limit is 4 accounts can be added.

There is a feature in the `az` cli that allows users to select an account from at max 4 registered in this Windows setting. I used this feature once before and was unable to switch back to the Web Account Manager (WAM) for the `az` cli and would like to understand what the process is to switch between them.

[image]

When logging into Azure with the WAM using the `az` cli, you will get this confirmation screen once your login is completed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I used this feature once before and was unable to switch back to the Web Account Manager (WAM) for the `az` cli and would like to understand what the process is to switch between them.

To switch from Windows Account Manager to Web Account Manager in PowerShell, here are the steps.

1. If you run the below command the default authentication goes to `Windows Account Manager`

> Note: If the value set to `True`, it indicates Windows-based authentication, which is registered in **Windows Local Accounts**

```
  az config set core.allow_broker=true  
     az account clear  
     az login
```

**Output of above command:**

[image]

2. Even if you set the authentication to `Windows Account Manager`, you can still log in with `Web-Based Authentication` by using `--use-device-code`.

```
   az login --use-device-code
```

**Output of above command:**

[image]

3. If you want to permanently change the default authentication to `web account manager`, set the value to `false`.

```
az config set core.allow_broker=false 
az account clear 
az login
```

**Output of above command:**

[image]